# <d3.js> Questions when drawing several lines with brush function

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, brush

I am trying to use d3 to draw several lines in one chart and also implement with brush function ( http://bl.ocks.org/1667367 )

[image]

Below part of code will show each line's name on the right side.

```
focudraw.select("text")
  .datum(function(d){
      return {name:d.name,value : d.values[d.values.length-1]};
  })
  .attr("transform",function(d){ 
      return "translate("+x(d.value.date)+","+y(d.value.price)+")"
    })
  .text(function(d){return d.name});
```

However, if I dynamic brushing when moving contextdraw(on the below) , that texts' position doesn't change , and I have no much idea to modify.

I think I should focus on focudraw.select("text") in brush function ,change the d.values' index right , I know how to map **new** x.domain()[ 1 ] to the last index of d.values , but the position is not so accurate ...

```
function brush(){
x.domain(brush.empty() ? navx.domain() : brush.extent());

focudraw.select("path").attr("d",function(d){
  return line(d.values);    
});


focudraw.select("text")
  .datum(function(d){
      return {name:d.name,value : d.values[d.values.length-1]};
  })
  .attr("transform",function(d){ 
      return "translate("+x(d.value.date)+","+y(d.value.price)+")"
    })
  .text(function(d){return d.name});


focu.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
```

}